# Profiling Java Apps with Java8

Tags: java

I am looking to profile certain Java servlet apps and some bean-based Java Apps. I have seen examples of from using `System.nanoTime()` to using these custom profilers (if they fit your budget).

The way I wanted to profile my apps at work is to basically check bottlenecks/slow-services, deadlocks, sudden high CPU usage. I do see some value in looking into memory usage per module (on a scaled system). Is there a right/tried-proven way to do this easily?

Thanks for your help in advance.